# how to revert cabal update on a different computer

Tags: haskell, cabal

I needed to compile a Haskell program an machine A which failed (for the `cryptonite` bug, which is not the issue here) but compiled on machine B. The difference was, that I had run `cabal update` on A but not on B recently. I was compiling with an older state of hackage on B than on A.

To fix the issue I need to

task 1: see which state of hackage I have on B.

task 2: force a `cabal update` to the same state on A.

I tried to find the required commands with `cabal update -h` and with search on the web, but could not identify them (and had to revert to use stack lts to progress).

what are the commands for task 1 and 2? with these commands, I could use cabal in a more controlled way and avoid surprises when some package in hackage breaks.

I am using linux (Debian 5.10.179-1 Debian 5.10.179-1) with

```
cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.6.2.0
compiled using version 3.6.2.0 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: If you know what package causes the problem, why not just add a version-constraint to that package? Reverting `cabal update` should really be a last-resort option when something used to work, now doesn't work anymore, and you really don't have time to properly nail down / address the problem at the moment.

Comment: unfortunately, the breaking code was deep in another package and why a version compiling before did not compile later (i.e. with a later version of `cabal update` is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know of a command to specifically query the timestamp, there are a few ways of getting cabal to display it. The least invasive one is possibly using [`cabal list`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.10/cabal-commands.html#cabal-list) with verbose output:

```bash
$ cabal -v --installed list base
Reading available packages of hackage.haskell.org...
Using historical state as of 2022-12-25T11:36:12Z specified from most recent
cabal update
index-state(hackage.haskell.org) = 2022-12-25T11:36:12Z (HEAD =
2023-06-08T09:48:09Z)
* base
    Synopsis: Basic libraries
    Default available version: 4.17.0.0
    Installed versions: 4.17.0.0
    License:  BSD-3-Clause
```

Once you have the desired timestamp, you can specify it when using `cabal update` in the other computer:

```bash
$ cabal update 'hackage.haskell.org,2022-12-25T11:36:12Z'
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Package list of hackage.haskell.org is up to date.
The index-state is set to 2022-12-25T11:36:12Z.
To revert to previous state run:
    cabal v2-update 'hackage.haskell.org,2023-06-08T09:48:09Z'
```

Since `cabal update` prints the old index timestamp, another option to find the timestamp would be updating, jotting down the old timestamp, and immediately reverting it. That's a bit more of a hassle than a read-only method, though.

Comment: @duplde: my ~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/01-index.timestamp contains only 'HEAD'. The rest of your advice worked perfectly, albeit a bit of character juggling. - In summary, the method gets a bit of the advantage of `stack LTS` (namely not being surprised by a breaking change in hackage) with the flexibility of `cabal`.

Comment: @user855443 You're right: that file shows just `HEAD` if you have ran `cabal update` without specifying a timestamp. That isn't very useful for our purposes, so I've removed it from the answer. Note there are some other means of having tighter control over versions, such as specifying them as needed in the cabal file (as leftaroundabout mentioned in a comment to the question), [specifying `index-state` in `cabal.project`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.10/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-index-state), or using `cabal freeze` to pin all versions in the project to whatever you're currently using.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I can include `index-state: 2016-09-24T17:47:48Z` in my `cabal.project` file (the cabal doc is very comprehensive, but difficult to understand for non-stecialists). i read https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/8047 and think I will start using `freeze`.  --  a simple question at end: where could I find a list of the possible cabal index-states?

Comment: @user855443 Any timestamp will work, resetting the index to the Hackage state at the time. For instance, the `2023-06-08T09:48:09Z` in the example above is just the time I had last ran `cabal update`.